# 3g dongle not working on el capitan

Tags: macos

My 3g dongle (micromax mmx352g) is working fine in the Mavericks in my MBP but in My MAC Mini which i upgrade to el capitan GM is not working .it's not even detecting the dongle. Is there any generic script or software that detects the 3g hardware and connect it internet via apn .

[image]

Comment: Did you already contact the vendor regarding a driver update?

Comment: yes,but they no longer provide support for the dongle that i have :(

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps

1. Restart Machine and press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting
2. It will take you to the Recovery Mode
3. From Utilities Menu open Terminal
4. In the Terminal Window enter `csrutil disable`
5. Then restart
6. Install regular EVO drivers that came with the dongle, you will be able to see the modem in *Network Preferences* and might have to do configuration manually like entering *99# as number etc.
7. Then restart in same mode as step 1
8. Open Terminal and enter `csrutil enable`

It will start working at step 6